# Tooltip in ASP.NET image button is not working properly in chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

Image button tooltip is showing as text in chrome

`<asp:ImageButton  ID="btnHelp" runat="server" AlternateText="" ToolTip="Help" />`

Here Help is showing as a text.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can get to the correct behavior is by setting `AlternateText` to a space:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnHelp" runat="server" AlternateText=" " ToolTip="Help" />
```

By the way, the behavior in Firefox is even more interesting: when `AlternateText` is empty, some text is displayed but I have no idea where it comes from. As is the case for Chrome, setting `AlternateText` to a space solves the problem.